# Undefined offset in wp-query

Tags: wordpress

Although I'm still getting results fine I'm getting an "Undefined offset: 0" error from my wp query which is annoying:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'custom_taxonomy', array("fields" => "all"));

foreach($terms as $term) {

    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $term->term_id,
                )
            )
        )
    );

    foreach ($posts as $post ) {

        if(count($post) < 1) {

        } else {

            echo $post->post_title;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried variations of !empty and checking count but none seem to be working. Any pointers please?

*Update*

If I remove the last foreach loop I'm still getting the undefined offset warning:

```
foreach($terms as $term) {

    $posts = get_posts(
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy',
                    'field' => 'term_id',
                    'terms' => $term->term_id,
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: You can just use if(count($post)) if $post= [] or $post= null the function count will return zero so that means that $postis empty.

Comment: All 3 of those options still give me the error :(.

Comment: Actually this is not error, this is an warning.

Comment: Yes you're right of course but I still have the warning and would like to fix it. I've updated my question with simplified code as this is giving me the warning.